# Problem Referencing JQuery With Master Pages

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a master page connected to the page I wanna put jquery on. On the master page the head tag is setup like this:

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="en-us" />
.... <---some css references
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script> 
.... <------some javascripty
</head>
```

The reference to the jquery being used here is 1.3.2 version which isnt compatible with the plugin I am using so I have to comment it out to make my page work

On my page I have the following

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <script src="../js/jquery_1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="../css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    ..... <---- then my jquery 
</Content>
```

I have 2 questions....

The main question is how come the jquery only fires when I comment out the jquery reference in the master page, but if I put

```
 <script src="../js/jquery_1.5.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

in the master page instead of the actual page and comment out the old jquery reference it still doesnt work. Why?

Also what I want is to get rid of the jquery 1.3.2 reference in the master page and replace it with the jquery_1.5.js without breaking anything and letting my code work in the content page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was

```
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
```

in the master page should under the reference to the jquery library, not above it.

Answer (score 0):

So may be you are referencing it wrong i.e. the path issue. Where is your masterpage and where is your .js file with reference to the root?

You can opt for using [CDN hosted jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery).

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: that isnt the issue, but thanks. If I was using 1.2.3 and now I wanna use 1.5.1 by removing 1.2.3 wont break anything right?

Comment: It depends if you are using other jquery plugins or stuff that relies exclusively on particular version. Otherwise you should be fine. And if something breaks due to jquery itself(not plugin) it will be easily fixable because jquery guys would be knowing that and will be well documented.

Comment: Sorry..looks like I need a break.